# How to kill the pm2 --no-daemon process

Tags: node.js, daemon, pm2, process-management

I'm using pm2 as the process manager of Node.js.

In many cases, I think I will run it as a daemon process, but if you use it locally as debugging, I think that there are times when you use the `--no-daemon` option.

How do I end the process when moving pm2 with this `--no-daemon` option?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You can try:

`pm2 kill`

or find the running PM2 process with:

`ps aux | grep PM2`

then kill with:

`kill -9 [pid]`

The `-9` switch sends the KILL signal to the process as opposed to the default interrupt (`INT` or `SIGINT`) signal and is equivalent to `-KILL` or `-SIGKILL`. Interrupt is a less invasive way and you could try that first to let the process gracefully exit, however, if it doesn't respond to that, the kill signal should result in an immediate termination (unless the process is zombie).

Comment: yes. certainly it can kill in that way. however, it is troublesome to make another window every time

Comment: I know understood.
command result is `PM2 God Daemon`.
The problem was solved when you played an `pm2 kill`.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: what is the opposite of pm2 kill though, i want to start all again

Comment: ➜  www pm2 kill         
[1]    511070 abort      pm2 kill, did u know why ?

Answer (score 54):

You can view all processes which are registered with pm2 using

```
pm2 list
```

Assume the process you want to stop is named as processA using the below command will stop the processA:

```
pm2 stop processA
```

In case you want to delete the process than use the below command:

```
pm2 delete processA
```

In case you don't want to kill a particular process but pm2 itself using the command below:

```
pm2 kill
```

Answer (score 15):

The right answer is **pm2 kill**

$**pm2 kill**
[PM2] [v] Modules Stopped
[PM2] Applying action deleteProcessId on app [all](ids: 0)
[PM2] hello ✓
[PM2] [v] All Applications Stopped
[PM2] [v] PM2 Daemon Stopped

Answer (score 9):

Other solution will be to run `pm2 delete all` or `pm2 stop all`. Which will not kill pm2 process itself, but will cleanup internal pm2's process list.

Answer (score 7):

First of all list all processes:

```
pm2 list
```

let suppose if your process is dev

```
pm2 stop dev
```

Now, delete the process

```
pm2 delete dev
```

after that process state became `daemon`.

If you want to kill that daemon process then run command

```
pm2 kill
```

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo pkill -f pm2
```

This should kill all processes of pm2 in linux

Answer (score 0):

One thing to add to the accepted answers. These commands only work for the current user. I had the same problem with a digitalocean droplet. I had logged in using "ubuntu" username, but I saw that the God Daemon is pointing to `/home/nodejs/.pm2`.

If this is the case, you need to switch to that user:
`sudo su nodejs`
And then run the pm2 kill commands from there.

Answer (score 0):

- You can find pm2 active process id from `cat ~/.pm2/pm2.pid`
- Then `kill xxx` (from above)

Answer (score -4):

If it's running in the foreground you should be able to kill it with `ctl + c`, same as you would kill `node server.js`.

Comment: I tried it.
but, when I run `pm2 list` the status will be still online

Comment: That should tell you that pm2 is not actually being run in the foreground. It has been daemonized into a background process. You should see it listed when running `top` or you can also search via @marekful 's suggestion above: `ps aux | grep PM2` to see if the pm2 process is running or not. What reason would you have for running it locally anyway?